# C++ - Could use a little explanation of Vec3b in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

I ran into this 'Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);' in some code I'm converting to another language.  I'm new to C++ OpenCV and was wondering where it is in the Documentation, I searched everywhere and couldn't find it.  I also grepped the entire OpenCV directory and found this to be the closest to a definition of it

'typedef Vec3b RGB;'

in the /home/w/Documents/opencv-master/modules/imgproc/test/test_cvtyuv.cpp file

I grepped for RGB and couldn't find a definition on that either though there was alot of output on it and I may have missed something.  I'm writing a C wrapper for it is why I need to know,  so far I have this to wrap the above 'Vec3b green(0,255,0)':

```
 Vec3b cv_create_Vec3b(const char* color, int val1, int val2, int val3) {
     return new Vec3b color (val1, val2, val3);
 }
```

But gets this error:

```
 opencv_generated.cpp:8:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘color’
      return new Vec3b color (val1, val2, val3);
                  ^
opencv_generated.cpp:8:45: error: ‘color’ cannot be used as a function
     return new Vec3b color (val1, val2, val3);
```

I, first of all, could use help, to find out how to type "color" .  It just needs a variable that would be "green" or "blue" whatever is input when it ran(new to C++ kind of)..Second just if someone could point me to or tell me info on it or show me a declaration on it so I'd have enough info to write my wrapper I'd be grateful.

Thank you
                                             ^

Comment: Your problems are not specific to `Vec3b`, but to C++. It is worth spending some time learning the basics of the language.

Comment: @ juanchopanza pls see latest comment to Arshia001

Comment: Your code us syntactically messed up in many ways, to the point that the intended semantics of your function are not clear.

Comment: @ juanchopanza pls see my new reworded question here 
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311634/c-help-writing-function-parameters-for-c-wrappers-for-c  

and thank you very much for getting back to me so soon =)

Answer (score 0):

Vec3b is a type (looks like a color value to me) and "green" and "blue" are variable names. You can't store variable names in strings (obviously) and hence you can't have a function which generates these values. Also, your function is syntactically wrong. While i don't understand how you would write a c wrapper to a c++ project (if part of it is in c++, you need a c++ compiler, so what's the point?), I'd definitely recommend you to learn c++ before attempting anything with it. The syntactic possibilities are too far and wide to just learn by yourself while reading code.

EDIT: maybe try something like this?

```
Vec3b Green() {
    Vec3b result(0, 255, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Thanks for your reply....I've already red a book on C++ and got a good amount of the language down,  I try and google the rest...Thats why I use S.O., when I can't find the answer in my texts or on google...Is there a way you can help me find out  how to do this particular task(defining a parameter to stand in for green and supply green to the Vec3b function inside my wrapper)..alot of the code I'm writing depends on it... Also I asked this question so I could get someone to tell me info on Vec3b because it doesn't appear to be readily available online or at least direct me to a resource.

Comment: Well, Vec3b is nothing special from what I can see, it's just a 3-byte color value. What I'd like to know is, what exactly do you mean by "wrapper"? How do you wrap object-oriented code into a language without support for OO? Anyway, you can try something like the code I added to the answer. Don't know if that's what you want or not though...

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it n another S.O. post. pls see comments

here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311634/c-help-writing-function-parameters-for-c-wrappers-for-c

```
Vec3b* cv_create_Vec3b(int val1, int val2, int val3) {
   return new Vec3b (val1, val2, val3);
}
```